# A simple exercise on integration by residues and an application of Jordan's lemma

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration, mobius-function

Since the **Möbius function** satisifies $$\mu(n)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}e^{2\pi i\frac{h}{n}},$$I define the (is a sequence for $n\geq 1$, I omit the subscript and write $f(z)$ instead of $f_n(z)$) function $$f(z)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\frac{e^{2\pi i\frac{h}{n}z}}{z^2+1}.$$

I've followed the strategy  in (spanish) [Ejemplo 16, in page 10, from  this course notes, Universidad Autónoma de Madrid](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/dragan/licenc/varcomI-0708-integr-not.pdf) to compute for $R$ enough large and $C_R$ the semicircle in the upper half plane that by **Cauchy** and **Residues Theorem** $$\int_{-R}^{R}+\int_{C_R}=\pi\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}e^{-2\pi i\frac{h}{n}}.$$
(And previous sum should be previous is equal to the **Möbius function**  since $$\Re\left(\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}e^{2\pi i\frac{h}{n}}\right)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\cos(-2\pi \frac{h}{n})=\Re\left(\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}e^{-2\pi \frac{h}{n}}\right)$$ holds, since this arithmetical funciton is real and the cosine function is even.)

Following the calculation one gets the estimation of the integrand as $$|f(z)|\leq \sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\frac{e^{-2\pi \frac{h}{n}R \sin t}}{R^2-1}$$ for the usual parametrisation and using the **triangle inequality**. Thus $$\left|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\right|\leq\frac{R}{R^2-1}\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\int_0^\pi e^{-2\pi \frac{h}{n}R \sin t} dt.$$

> **Question.** And now I need a modified **Jordan's Lemma** (in the course notes *Lema de Jordan*) to compute previous as $$\left|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\right|\leq\text{something}\to 0$$
>   as $R$ tends to infinity. Can you do this step?

Then I could finish this simple exercise to refresh complex integration, if there are no mistakes in my calculations, and sates that for this (sequence) function $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\frac{e^{-2\pi \frac{h}{n}x}}{x^2+1}dx=\pi\mu(n).$$
In this last step one can deduce also the corresponding integral for the cosine function in the integrand when one takes the real part of previous identity.

Thus can you say if there were some mistake or can you improve some fact and answer previous **Question 1** to know how apply a **Jordan Lemma** to finish the exercise? **Many thanks.**

Comment: it is obvious that $\int_{C_R^+} f(z) dz \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ with $C_R^+ = \{ |z| = R, Im(z) > 0\}$ since $f(z) = \frac{\mathcal{O}(1)}{z^2+1}$, i.e. you are integrating $\mathcal{O}(R^{-2})$ on a curve of length $\mathcal{O}(R)$, so the result is $\mathcal{O}(R^{-1})$

Comment: now I'd say considering instead $g_x(z) = \sum_{n < x} f_n(z)$ whose residue at $z=i$ is $\pi M(x)$ (the Mertens function) could be interesting, and will yield an estimate of $M(x)$ related to the Farey sequences

Comment: With respect your first comment feel free to add an answer. From the exercise that I tried follow, is used the **Lema de Jordan**, and I think that also it is possible deduce a kind of such lemma to state the statement. But very thanks much for your valuable answer. With respect your second feel free to study your approach. Many thanks @user1952009

Comment: For the BOUNTY, I accept the proof using a modified Jordan's Lemma or well the more detailed explanation of the contribution of previous user in  comments. Many thanks.

Comment: You have made some mistakes here. The Mobius function takes negative values. Your last expression is a integral of a stricktly positive function and therefore positive. Another way to see there's an error; the integrand $e^{-2\pi\frac{h}{n}x}/(1+x^2)$ diverges as $x\to -\infty$ so the integral does not exist.

Comment: One error is in $\cos(-x) = \Re[e^{-x}]$. The correct statement is $\cos(-x) = \Re[e^{-ix}]$ (with the $i$ in the exponent).

Comment: Very thanks much @Winther. Then have meaning the questions now? At least has meaning the main question about complex integration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Winther please,if you or other user then can do a contribution to this question, it is the best, since you've detect such mistake.

Comment: The main question is already answered in the first comment. You can finish it off from your own calculations by using $e^{-(\cdots)} \leq 1$ since $\sin(t) \geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$ so $\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-(\cdots)} {\rm d}t \leq \pi$ and $|\int f| < \frac{R}{R^2-1}\cdot n\cdot \pi$ (as the sum as atmost $n$ terms) which goes to $0$ as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: The problem also is the bounty I prefer pay the bounty to an user, notice that the main purpose of this site that we can have the best reference/calculations and their justifications for each question. Very thanks much @Winther

Comment: @user1952009 also you, and all users, are welcome to add a detailed answer. My genuine though was that get the justification was difficult. Thanks.

Comment: You have to download some books on : complex analysis, analytic number theory, $\zeta(s)$, and do all the exercices. And 99% of your questions have answer on the forum, so you have to learn how to find them (as we do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up factors of i. There are different ways to write a correct formula, e.g.:

$$\oint_C \sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}\frac{e^{\pm \,2\pi \frac{h}{n}z}}{z^2+1}dz=\pi\mu(n)$$

when $C$ is a contour encircling $i$ but not $-i$. Depending on the choice of sign in the exponential you need either ${\rm Re}\; z$ bounded from below or from above along the contour for the integral to be convergent so you will not be able to relate this to an integral over ${\Bbb R}$. Note that in your 3rd formula there is a factor of i too much in the exponent. The following is correct given the definitions in your text:

$$\int_{-R}^{R}+\int_{C_R}=\pi\sum_{\substack{1\leq h\leq n\\(h,n)=1}}e^{-2\pi \frac{h}{n}}$$

The second equality in your  4th equation is not correct (and not justified by your text):

What is your aim with these calculations?

Comment: Very thanks much for your answer, and **Winther** and **user1952009.** my aim was encourage to study more complex analysis, and understand if there are more interesting links between classical number theoretic  functions and complex analysis. I believe that my question is not a good question because there were mistakes, but thanks to your contribution and previous users, those mistakes are being clarified. My purpose is try understand what's is an integer.